# Google Vision's Python Client Quickstart throws TypeError: bases must be types

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to run the [quickstart](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/main/samples/snippets/quickstart/quickstart.py) from Google's Vision python library locally. However, when I run `python3 quickstart.py` I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/penguin/.../quickstart.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(run_quickstart())
  File "/Users/penguin/.../quickstart.py", line 25, in run_quickstart
    from google.cloud import vision
  File "/Users/pengui/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/vision/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision_v1.services.image_annotator.async_client import (
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.vision_helpers.decorators import add_single_feature_methods
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import proto
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .enums import Enum
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proto/enums.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/builder.py", line 42, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/reflection.py", line 51, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import message_factory
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/message_factory.py", line 42, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation
  File "/Users/penguin/anaconda3/envs/vision/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.py", line 104, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
TypeError: bases must be types
```

What I know is:

- This doesn't happen when I run quickstart in the Google CloudShell
- I am using the right creds, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
- I am using python 3.9.12 locally
- I installed [requirements.txt](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/main/samples/snippets/quickstart/requirements.txt) using pip3 (google-cloud-vision==2.7.2)
- python3 and pip3 are both in the right `/anaconda3/envs/vision` path.
- My OS is macOS Monterey 12.4

I am not sure at what point in this stack trace that the error is occurring, or how to fix it.

Comment: You generally "read" stacktraces bottom up. They're listed top-down because the first line #53 in `quickstart.py` threw an error that was caused by the 2nd line ... caused by the nth line etc. The `TypeError` resulted from `from google.protobuf.pyext import _message`. What version of `protobuf` does `pip freeze | grep protobuf` yield?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I just cannot bring my head around how from google.protobuf.pyext import _message could throw a type error. Also, the answer to your question is: protobuf==4.21.1

Comment: You can repro the error directly by running a Python3 REPL in the virtualenv that you've built for the sample. And then `from google.protobuf.pyext import _message` to see what happens.

Comment: Google has made [some significant changes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06) to `protobuf`. Can you try reverting to [v3.20.1](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.20.1) to see whether that before-the-big-change release works? `pip uninstall protobuf && pip install protobuf==3.20.1`. You could then try the REPL and `from google.protobuf.pyext import _message` to confirm whether the error persists. Alternatively, perhaps (guess) try [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#sharing-messages)

Answer (score 6):

According to @DazWilkin's comment, downgrade the protobuf package as follows.

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.20.1
```

It worked just fine for me. `tensorflow` and `protobuf` versions were incompatible in my case.